# Windows 7 port opening issue

Tags: windows-7, port

I set up a web server on my Windows 7 computer and want to open port 80 so outside computers can visit my web server.

At first, I thought it was the firewall blocking the port, so I created a new rule in Windows Firewall to allow connections on port 80. That did not work.

Then I turned off the whole firewall; it still did not work.

I just don't know what to do now. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Does your server have a public IP? If not you have to set up [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Comment: Thanks. It's for network inside a router, problem solved. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Skype locks the port 80 by default. Change its settings to use another one.

If you *can* open the port and your server is working at *localhost* but nobody outside can access it, its probably your ISP imposing limitations. Some ISPs won't allow regular home users to open certain service ports like 21 (FTP), 22 (SSH), 25 (SMTP), 53 (DNS), 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS) etc.

Comment: Thanks. I checked again and finds out that another firewall software blocked port 80. I add a rule to it and it works, thanks anyway